# Display taxonomy with a maximum number of letters

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, hooks, actions

I'm looking for a function which displays a post's taxonomy with a maximum number of letters. I've achieved with title ([How to limit the max number of characteres in the title that are displayed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-to-limit-the-max-number-of-characteres-in-the-title-that-are-displayed/127965#127965)), but I'm not able to do it with taxonomies.

E.g. I have this:

```
echo '<div class="artistas-review" style="font-size: 0.7em; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: -10px; padding: 3px;">'.get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'Artistas', '<div class="artista">', '</div>' ).'</div>';
```

This shows the "Artistas" taxonomy. I want to show only the first 10 letters. Any idea of how to hook in to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP to limit the strings, just as in the example you mention. However, we can just build the terms list ourselves, so we don't have to write any filter. We use "get_the_terms" instead, which returns an array of strings, that we can then output and shorten:

```
<?php
$max = 30; //define your max characters here    
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'Artistas' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
  echo '<div class="artista">';
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_name = $term->name;
    if( strlen( $term_name ) > $max ) {
      $term_name = substr( $term_name, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";
    }
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'Artistas' ).'" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
endif;
?>
```

That should output a list of links wrapped inside your div (if I didn't make any typo ;)
Note that the "&hellip" thing is whatever you want to put behind a cut string, in this case it's 3 dots.

Cheers.